# Incompatible conversion while assigning even tho i catch it with an if statement C++11

Tags: c++, templates, casting, variadic-templates

```cpp
template <typename T> using Map = std::map<std::string, T>;
class object_index {
public:
  object_index(){};
  int cntr = 0;
  Map<int> MapInt;
  Map<bool> MapBool;
  Map<std::string> MapStr;
  Map<double> MapDouble;
  template <typename V> void insert2Map(V lhs) {
    if (std::is_same<V, int>::value) {
      std::cout << "INT: ";
      std::string key = std::to_string(cntr);
      MapInt[key] = lhs; // ERROR 
/* incompatible pointer to integer conversion assigning to 
'std::map<std::basic_string<char>, int>::mapped_type' 
(aka 'int') from 'const char *'  */
    }
    if (std::is_same<V, const char *>::value) {
      std::cout << "STR: ";
    }

    if (std::is_same<V, bool>::value) {
      std::cout << "BOOL: ";
    }

    if (std::is_same<V, double>::value) {
      std::cout << "DOUBLE: ";
    }

    std::cout << lhs << std::endl;
  }
  template <typename Ob> object_index &operator,(Ob obj) {
    insert2Map(obj);
    ++cntr;
    return *this;
  }
  // o1[values 1.3, 2, 4, "hello"];
};

class object {
public:
  void operator[](object_index index) { item = index; }

private:
  object_index item;
};
#define values object_index(),

int main(void) {

  object o1 = object();
  o1[values 1.3, 2, true, "hello"];
  
 

  return 0;
}
```

DISCLAIMER:: I know there is no reason to use this weird syntax , its for a Uni project that asks for this.

It should never get an argument of an incompatible type , I check for it before using it. How can i get past this? Or is the compiler right? How can I achieve this correctly?

Comment: `if (std::is_same...` -> `if constexpr (std::is_same...`

Comment: `constexpr if` is a C++17 extension. Is there a way to do this in c++11?

Comment: You say that your Uni requires "this weird syntax". It is not clear how much of it is allowed to change.

Comment: I am talking about this `o1[values 1.3, 2, true, "hello"];` . The rest of the code just has to be c++11 standard.

Comment: Just write 4 separate overloads of `insert2Map` instead of a single template.